# Python 3.7.2: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Here I have the following code:

```
 N = 5
    X = [3,-4,4,-3,4]
    Y = 0
    U = 0
    V = 0
    T=[]
    K=[]

    T.append(0)
    K.append(0)

    i = 1
    imin = i-1
    while (i<=N):
        T.append(T[i-1]+X[i])
        if T[i]>0:
            if T[i-1]>0:
                K.append(K[i-1])
            else: K.append(i)
        else:
            K.append(i)
        i += 1


    Y = 0
    U = 0
    V = 0
    print(T)
    while(i!=N):
        if T[i]>Y:
            Y = T[i]
            U = K[i]
            V = i
        i+=1
```

The problem is that the code can't pass the line **T.append(T[i-1]+X[i])** because of IndexError.
As an example, at the beginning of the code, T[i-1] is T[0], which is already defined as 0. X[0] is defined too, it is 3.
What is the problem then?

Thanks for everyone who helps me out!

Comment: When i = N = 5, X[i] is out of bounds.

Comment: @JohnColeman if i=1 then X[1] is the second element of X, which is -4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is going all the way up to `i=5`, and the last valid element of `X` is `X[4]`.  `X[5]` is what's raising the `IndexError`.

Answer (score 4):

Change the line `while (i<=N):` to `while (i<N):` and the error no longer occurs. I'm not sure however that this provides the expected outcome because you haven't specified what you're trying to do.